# Compiling third party .h files into DLL to PInvoke unmanaged code

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, pinvoke

I am developing a Form Aplication in VB .NET in order to automate some tasks in a Computer Assisted Manufacturing Software. The distributor provide a SDK with some header files in C++, which can be used to perform some tasks inside the software. As just some part of my program has to use these functions, I feel more confortable programming in VB to build the interface and interact with the user. I want to use PInvoke to call the functions declared in the header files, but in order to do so they has to be compiled and exported in a DLL library. How can I build a DLL from the header files?

Comment: You can't build a DLL from header files. The header files (typically) define the interface but not the implementation.

Comment: So the implementation is in other files I suppose are included also in the SDK.

Comment: The compiled DLL must be somewhere, yes. Either in the SDK or perhaps in the standard, end user package? (if there is one) -- The headers exist for implementation with lower level languages such as C or C++.